# using linq to filter out undesirable objects

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I wrote this linq query in this method so I can filter out any ships in my fleet that don't have a linked module(storage, life support, medical bay, etc).

This returns true if the provided fleet has any ship with linked modules

```
    public bool FleetWithShipsWithLinkedModules(Fleet fleet)
    {
        var linkedModules = fleet.Ships.Any(
                                        s => s != null &&
                                        s.Parts != null &&
                                        s.Parts.LinkedModules != null);

        return linkedModules;
    }
```

usage:

```
if (FleetWithShipsWithLinkedModules(fleet))
{
   ...do stuff
}
```

In the database, the Parts are linked to Ships, not the Fleets. It goes Fleet > Ships > Parts

It works about 50% of the time and I can't figure out why.  I am not sure if I it's the linq or something else.

I was hoping someone could take a look at the linq query and let me know if it looks ok structurally and syntax-wise.

Thanks!

Comment: You realise you're not actually filtering out ships here? You're just checking whether *any* ships in your fleet have parts with linked modules.

Comment: What is data type of linked modules ? Is it collection or single object ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are null-checking collections, while you should check whether or not they're empty:

```
var linkedModules = fleet.Ships
                         .Any(s => s.Parts
                                    .Any(p => p.LinkedModules.Any());
```